# Does ぴゃhave a meaning?

Tags: meaning, words, usage

A person sent an email on a phone, and exclaimed "pya" after sending it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ぴゃっ/ぴゃーっ/ピャーッ/ぴゃっと/ぴゃぴゃっと/etc is an onomatopoeia that describes something moving very quickly. さーっと/ささっと/さっと is similar. [This page](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B4%E3%82%83%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8) says it's an Osaka dialect word.

> - 家にぴゃーっと帰ります！
> - ぴゃぴゃっと行って来い！

So the ぴゃ you saw describes how the email has been sent to you (quickly).